# How to set value of multiple input fields with same button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to set input field value only when it is clicked and want to set value in two different input fields from same button, when one input field is selected only set value in this field when other selected/clicked value set their.

Try with different ways but not successful.
I hope i will be helped in this problem.

thanks

```js
var phoneScreen = $("#phone"); var phoneNumber = phoneScreen.val();
var delBtn = $("#del"); var clrBtn = $("#clr");
var numBtn = $(".number");

numBtn.click(function() {
    var number = $(this).val();
  updatePhoneNumber(number);
  printPhoneNumber();
});
delBtn.click(function() {
    deleteNumber();
  printPhoneNumber();
});
clrBtn.click(function() {
    clearNumber();
  printPhoneNumber();
});

function updatePhoneNumber(newNumber) {
    phoneNumber = phoneNumber + newNumber;
}
function deleteNumber() {
    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.slice(0,-1);
}
function clearNumber() {
    phoneNumber = "";
}
function printPhoneNumber() {
    phoneScreen.val(phoneNumber);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <style>
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="number" id="phone" placeholder="(123) 45-7" min="0" step="1"/>

<input type="number" id="phone2" placeholder="(123) 45-7" min="0" step="1"/>

<form action="#" method="post" id="form">
<button type="button" class="rightside__pad-btn number" value="1">1</button>
<button type="button" type="button" class="rightside__pad-btn number" value="2">2</button>
<button type="button" type="button" class="rightside__pad-btn number" value="3">3</button>
<br />
<button type="button" type="button" class="rightside__pad-btn number" value="4">4</button>
<button type="button" type="button" class="rightside__pad-btn number" value="5">5</button>
<button type="button" type="button" class="rightside__pad-btn number" value="6">6</button>
<br />
<button type="button" type="button" class="rightside__pad-btn number" value="7">7</button>
<button type="button" type="button" class="rightside__pad-btn number" value="8">8</button>
<button type="button" type="button" class="rightside__pad-btn number" value="9">9</button>
<br />
<button type="button" id="del" class="rightside__pad-btn del">
</button>
<button type="button" class="rightside__pad-btn number" value="0">0</button>
<button type="button" id="dial" class="rightside__pad-btn" value="">
</button>
    
    
    </form>

  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added few changes

1. `var hasFocus = $('#phone');` Set `#phone` as default focused element.
2. Update the `hasFocus` to selected input element.

```
   $('input[type=number]').on('click', function(){
      hasFocus = $(this);
    });
```

Now added function to set value to focused element `hasFocus.val(hasFocus.val() +number);`

Please update

```js
var phoneScreen = $("#phone"); 
var phoneNumber = phoneScreen.val();
var delBtn = $("#del"); var clrBtn = $("#clr");
var numBtn = $(".number");
var hasFocus = $('#phone');
$('input[type=number]').on('click', function(){
  hasFocus = $(this);
})
numBtn.click(function() {
    var number = $(this).val();  
    hasFocus.val(hasFocus.val() +number);
  //updatePhoneNumber(number);
  //printPhoneNumber(number);
});
delBtn.click(function() {
    deleteNumber();
  printPhoneNumber();
});
clrBtn.click(function() {
    clearNumber();
  printPhoneNumber();
});

function updatePhoneNumber(newNumber) {
    phoneNumber = phoneNumber + newNumber;
}
function deleteNumber() {
    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.slice(0,-1);
}
function clearNumber() {
    phoneNumber = "";
}
function printPhoneNumber() {
    phoneScreen.val(phoneNumber);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <style>
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="number" id="phone" placeholder="(123) 45-7" min="0" step="1"/>

<input type="number" id="phone2" placeholder="(123) 45-7" min="0" step="1"/>

<form action="#" method="post" id="form">
<button type="button" class="rightside__pad-btn number" value="1">1</button>
<button type="button" type="button" class="rightside__pad-btn number" value="2">2</button>
<button type="button" type="button" class="rightside__pad-btn number" value="3">3</button>
<br />
<button type="button" type="button" class="rightside__pad-btn number" value="4">4</button>
<button type="button" type="button" class="rightside__pad-btn number" value="5">5</button>
<button type="button" type="button" class="rightside__pad-btn number" value="6">6</button>
<br />
<button type="button" type="button" class="rightside__pad-btn number" value="7">7</button>
<button type="button" type="button" class="rightside__pad-btn number" value="8">8</button>
<button type="button" type="button" class="rightside__pad-btn number" value="9">9</button>
<br />
<button type="button" id="del" class="rightside__pad-btn del">
</button>
<button type="button" class="rightside__pad-btn number" value="0">0</button>
<button type="button" id="dial" class="rightside__pad-btn" value="">
</button>
    
    
    </form>

  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below code:

```js
var activeElement = '';
var phoneNumber = '';

var phoneScreen = $("#phone"); 
phoneScreen.focusin(function() {
 console.log('phoneScreen');
 phoneNumber = phoneScreen.val();
 activeElement = phoneScreen;
});

var phoneScreen2 = $("#phone2"); 
phoneScreen2.focusin(function() {
 console.log('phoneScreen2');
 phoneNumber = phoneScreen2.val();
 activeElement = phoneScreen2;
});

var delBtn = $("#del"); var clrBtn = $("#clr");
var numBtn = $(".number");

numBtn.click(function() {
  var number = $(this).val();
  updatePhoneNumber(number);
  printPhoneNumber();
});
delBtn.click(function() {
    deleteNumber();
  printPhoneNumber();
});
clrBtn.click(function() {
  clearNumber();
  printPhoneNumber();
});

function updatePhoneNumber(newNumber) {
    phoneNumber = phoneNumber + newNumber;
}
function deleteNumber() {
    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.slice(0,-1);
}
function clearNumber() {
    phoneNumber = "";
}
function printPhoneNumber() {
    activeElement.val(phoneNumber);
    activeElement.focus();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <style>
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="number" id="phone" placeholder="(123) 45-7" min="0" step="1"/>

<input type="number" id="phone2" placeholder="(123) 45-7" min="0" step="1"/>

<form action="#" method="post" id="form">
<button type="button" class="rightside__pad-btn number" value="1">1</button>
<button type="button" type="button" class="rightside__pad-btn number" value="2">2</button>
<button type="button" type="button" class="rightside__pad-btn number" value="3">3</button>
<br />
<button type="button" type="button" class="rightside__pad-btn number" value="4">4</button>
<button type="button" type="button" class="rightside__pad-btn number" value="5">5</button>
<button type="button" type="button" class="rightside__pad-btn number" value="6">6</button>
<br />
<button type="button" type="button" class="rightside__pad-btn number" value="7">7</button>
<button type="button" type="button" class="rightside__pad-btn number" value="8">8</button>
<button type="button" type="button" class="rightside__pad-btn number" value="9">9</button>
<br />
<button type="button" id="del" class="rightside__pad-btn del">
</button>
<button type="button" class="rightside__pad-btn number" value="0">0</button>
<button type="button" id="dial" class="rightside__pad-btn" value="">
</button>
    
    
    </form>

  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: On what condition, both inputs could be editable? At a time, only one input can be focused. Anyway, setting value in both the input is possible.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer